# Jenkins + Maven + Github

Tags: maven, selenium, github, jenkins

I am having issues trying to configure Jenkins on my local machine to run a Mavent Test that I uploaded to my github.

Can anyone help me configure my jenkins job to pull my maven tests from github

Comment: more detials pls, is it free style job or multi config job...if it's free style job then do check the console/output when u run the Job and let us know what error u are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to specify the git repositories.
2. Git access/credential.
3. Branch that you want to checkout the code.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Well first you need to specify what github url to pull from..

In your job configuration, set the repo url and branch that you'd like to pull.

Also, it does say that the git executable does not exist in `/Users/Andrew/Desktop/QA`
this might be something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

Tried doing this again with a repository that is public and on github & my desktop

I am not sure actually how/where to begin. My github url is 
github.com/FinalTrigger/automation

Github project is https://github.com/FinalTrigger/automation

Under Source Code Management
repository URL is : https://github.com/FinalTrigger/automation.git
and my credentials is my user login and password but I get this error in red:

**Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git config --local credential.helper store --file=\"/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/git1200959093531126931.credentials\"**

Branch to build : */master

Since this is a maven project I assume that the Build would be "Invoke top-level maven targets". 
Maven Version : Maven
Goals : What do I put
Pom : what do I put
Properties : What do I put
JVM Options : What Do I put

(I can do without the source code management if all that means is for this to work) I apologize in advanced for the noob like thread. Also it wont let me post more than 2 links (images).